# Single index to measure the randomness of multivariate distributions (or data)

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, randomness

Are there any single indices to *roughly* measure the degree of total randomness of a multivariate distribution (or data)?

For example, assuming I know the covariance matrix $S$ of a multivariate random variable $X$, how can I measure $X$'s "total randomness" by some single number? Some of my wild guesses,

1. The Frobenius Norm of $S$?
2. Maximum/mimimum/mean of eigen values of $S$?
3. Trace of $S$?

Comment: I just noticed that, entropy (if we know the type of distribution, e.g. Gaussian) can be one candidate.

Comment: What are you actually trying to measure when you refer to "randomness"? A variable being random would mean that past data cannot predict future data, I guess you meant the word "random" in a more informal way.

Comment: @Hugh yes, I am analysing prediction performance on various datasets. By randomness I roughly mean variance and my hypothesis is the more random the data, the worse the performance.

Answer (score 1):

You may use principal component analysis (PCA) to get an idea on how many common factors are driving these variables. Follow the following steps

1. calculate the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix and rank the
   eigenvalues from the largest to the smallest.
2. Calculate (sum of top eigenvalues) / (sum of all eigenvalues)

For example, if the top three (3) eigenvalues account for 90% of the total eigenvalues, it intuitively means that the variables are primarily driven by three factors. '

In many cases, very high dimension data are actually driven by just a few underlying factors.

Comment: Good idea! But this only applies when the first component is dominant, right (I must use one single index)?

Comment: The components are sorted descending with respect to their eigenvalues. Therefore the first component per definition is the most dominant. You could therefore compute a single index such as "the amount of variance explained by the first three components" - which is the sum of the normalized eigenvalues.